# Cucumber - Ways to find the total number of features/scenarios when the test execution starts?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am working on a custom report formatter for a cucumber test framework. I have 20+ feature files and contains different tags for each files. I am using Cucumber CLI and passing specific tags to execute the tests.

**Problem:**

I need to implment a progress report which shows how many scenarios were executed Vs how many scenarios are still remaining to be executed. The report will dynamically show the progress in terms % of test completion.  I am able to count the total number of scenarios executed as it either passes/ fails using the `@After` hooks.
However i am unable to find the total number of scenarios to be executed.
I have tried to implement the `concurrentevent listener` for `TestRunStarted` Event. but it does not provide any summary details. I believe Cucumber Runtime model may be able to provide this information, but could not get it to work. If you have solved similar problem, please post it here. Appreciate any help/ideas to solve this.

Comment: Long story short. You can't. Cucumber doesn't generate a test plan. However you can use JUnit 5 Platform with Cucumber and then use the JUnit Platform Apis to launch Cucumber.  Junit 5 does generate a test plan.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-execution

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje ok.thanks. I will try the Junit runner route.  Most of our developers are using cucumber in the automation framework. It would be good if we can implement this feature in cucumber.

Comment: Don't see that happening any time soon. JUnit 5 does a better job at it then we ever could.